# fluent nHibernate and relation to Asp.net Membership tables

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-membership

I'm using fluent nHibernate (automapper) and at the same time use Asp.net Membership, but how do i reference aspnet_Users table?

maybe create a new user table with only the ProviderUserKey as field? and always make references to that table? and use Membership.GetUser(..) to get name etc.

Comment: @Carl which code did u finally go for to implmenet membership with nh? any links?

Comment: first i implemented my own MembershipProvider, but then i dropped it, started using WIF (http://blogs.msdn.com/card/archive/2009/11/18/windows-identity-foundation-wif-rtm-announced.aspx) instead, abstracting away the authentication bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and abstract away the whole authentication thing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/card/archive/2009/11/18/windows-identity-foundation-wif-rtm-announced.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should implement new Membership provider with NHibernate.
But...why do it if someone else did it already...

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=nhibernate%20membership%20provider&btnG=Search